# Jmeter Slave machine is not sending back any results to master machine

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter distributed testing to run JMX files in remote machines. Both are connected well and remote machine is not sending back any results to me. It says just started test and finished the test. but no results are being sent back to Master machine.

Comment: What is your RMI configuration?

Comment: Hey @d4Rk and automatictester can you please check these.. i am unable to copy my entire code so i am giving drive link for properties file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwT8KgzXMBEHUkYteDZ0Wkd1WW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Most of the time this is a problem with either Firewalls or the RMI configuration as mentioned by automatictester. It's hard to tell what exactly the problem is without more information about your network and setup of servers and client.

Comment: Ok let me tell you guys how i am activating my slave machine. While using the command -s jmeter-server i am getting this error "Cannot start. hari-Latitude-3540 is a loopback address".....

Answer (score 0):

It's a communication problem between slave and master.

Ensure you set this value in JMeter user.properties file to a value different from 0, let's say 4000 and open corresponding ports 4000, 4001, 4002 :

- client.rmi.localport=0